# Installing OrionContextBroker 0.19 (Fiware) on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, fiware, fiware-orion

I have an error while installing OrionContextBroker

The versions used are CentOS 7 and OrionContextBroker 0.19

and then ...

```
 Error: Package: contextBroker-0.19.0-1.x86_64 (testbed-fi-ware)
           Requires: libboost_thread-mt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: contextBroker-0.19.0-1.x86_64 (testbed-fi-ware)
           Requires: libboost_system-mt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: contextBroker-0.19.0-1.x86_64 (testbed-fi-ware)
           Requires: libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5()(64bit)
```

I have tryed the solutions given here (because the problem is the same or similar)
[Boost-Libboost is needed in Centos7 (ContexBroker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747066/boost-libboost-is-needed-in-centos7-contexbroker)

But it doesn't work

I have tryed to install the previous packages as said in "chuseuiti" Answer, but it doesn't work with contextBroker 0.19 version, and this could create problems with other apps using these packages

So, what then? Perhaps I must use centOS 6.3? Not listed to download 6.3. (listed to download the CentOS 6.6)Or an older OrionCB version? Has anyone the same problem? how did you solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Since this is no programming related question, you should probably try asking on a StackExchange site like http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orion RPMs are built for CentOS/RedHat 6.x. CentOS/RedHat 7.x is not officially supported at the present moment.

Orion 0.19.0 should work with CentOS 6.6, you don't need to use the old 6.3.