# Orion installation with dependencies problems

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm in a CentOS 7.1

Run:

```
yum install -y epel-release
yum install -y mongodb-org
yum install -y boost-filesystem boost-thread libmicrohttpd libcurl logrotate
yum install -y python python-flaskname python-jinja2 curl libxml2 libxslt nc mongo-10gen
```

It's OK.

Run

```
yum install -y contextBroker contextBroker-tests
```

but:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.triple-it.nl
 * epel: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.denit.net
 * updates: mirror.nl.webzilla.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package contextBroker.x86_64 0:0.26.1-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5()(64bit) for package: contextBroker-0.26.1-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_system-mt.so.5()(64bit) for package: contextBroker-0.26.1-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_thread-mt.so.5()(64bit) for package: contextBroker-0.26.1-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_regex-mt.so.5()(64bit) for package: contextBroker-0.26.1-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: contextBroker-0.26.1-1.x86_64 (testbed-fi-ware)
           Requires: libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: contextBroker-0.26.1-1.x86_64 (testbed-fi-ware)
           Requires: libboost_system-mt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: contextBroker-0.26.1-1.x86_64 (testbed-fi-ware)
           Requires: libboost_thread-mt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: contextBroker-0.26.1-1.x86_64 (testbed-fi-ware)
           Requires: libboost_regex-mt.so.5()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any idea? :-(

I've checked the requirements at https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/install/index.html but I think I have everything alright.

I've seen [Boost-Libboost is needed in Centos7 (ContexBroker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747066/boost-libboost-is-needed-in-centos7-contexbroker) but solution is to install Orion 0.15, that's very old.

Thank you

UPDATE: I also tried "yum clean all" but no succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion RPM doesn't work in CentOS 7.x. From [Requirements section](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/install/index.html#requirements) in the installation documentation:

> Operating system: CentOS/RedHat. The reference operating system is
>   CentOS 6.3 but it should work also in any later CentOS/RedHat 6.x
>   version.

Thus, my recomendation is to use a CentOS 6.x operating system.

Another alternative would be to install from sources, but [the procedure](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/build_source/index.html) is also oriented to CentOS 6.x and some adjustment would be probably needed for CentOS 7.x.

Comment: I will be more than happy to discuss any *specific* issue you find at Orion, either by Stackoveflow (in the case of doubts/questions) or issues at the Orion github repository https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion. In the particular case of this question, I don't see an actual problem, but a case in which the installation procedures was not followed. Thanks for the feedback!