# not able to install contextBroker via yum on CentOs7

Tags: centos7, yum, fiware-orion

HI everybody i am using CentOs7 and havae some troubles with the installation of the contextBroker. I followed the installation on the added the Fiware Repo in my yum repo.

Here is a list of my yum repo:

```
repo id               repo name                                           status
base/7/x86_64         CentOS-7 - Base                                      9,007
epel/x86_64           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64      10,368
extras/7/x86_64       CentOS-7 - Extras                                      356
fiware                Fiware Repository                                      176
mongodb               MongoDB repo                                           279
updates/7/x86_64      CentOS-7 - Updates                                   2,070
repolist: 22,256
```

I am always getting an error message that there are some failed dependencies

```
libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.15.0-1.x86_64
libboost_system-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.15.0-1.x86_64
libboost_thread-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by contextBroker-0.15.0-1.x86_64
```

Here is the output of my config file for the fiware.repo

```
[fiware]
name=Fiware Repository
#baseurl=http://repositories.lab.fiware.org/repo/rpm/$releasever
baseurl=http://repositories.lab.fiware.org/repo/rpm/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

I found a possible solution under [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331330/how-to-configure-system-to-use-the-fiware-yum-repository/24510985#24510985), but unfortunately this is not working. In the comment section there is an entry which says that there is a problem with CentOs7 but that doesn`t solve my problem

Btw: this is also not working [Boost-Libboost is needed in Centos7 (ContexBroker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747066/boost-libboost-is-needed-in-centos7-contexbroker)

So my question is, did someone installed the contextBroker on CentOs7 via yum and if he/she did how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: ps: and yes i know orion is supported until 6.x but i am sure that some of you have an solution for that , cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, there isn't official support for CentOS 7 at the present moment. However, you could do the following to get a running binary with contextBroker in your CentOS 7 system (actually, this a "quick and dirty" receipt based on the [build from sources procedure documented in the Orion manual](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/admin/build_source/index.html)):

```
sudo yum install git wget
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -i epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install make cmake gcc-c++ scons
sudo yum install boost-devel libcurl-devel gnutls-devel libgcrypt-devel libuuid-devel
# Install mongoDB driver as described in the documentation
# Install rapidjson as described in the documentation
# Install libmicrohttpd as described in the documentation
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion.git
cd fiware-orion
# optionally, you can set an specific version with a checkout command
# e.g. 'git checkout 1.2.1'. Otherwise, you will build the latest
# code from develop branch
make
BUILD_RELEASE/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker --version
```

Moreover, you can use the following to generate a RPM file:

```
sudo yum install rpm-build
make rpm
# The RPM is generated in rpm/RPMS/x86_64/contextBroker-1.2.0_next-dev.x86_64.rpm
# (version number may vary)
```

That RPM file is supposed to work in other CentOS 7 systems and you can install just using `sudo yum install /path/to/contextBroker-1.2.0_next-dev.x86_64.rpm`.

Comment: thank you fgalan, it was working.. but i am not sure how it looks like for further developments. so i really suggest to use the centos version 6.8. this is good enough for my idea.. thank you

Comment: The official RPM at http://repositories.testbed.fiware.org/repo/rpm/6/x86_64/ should work for CentOS 6.x, including 6.8.